# Do any communities permit music during Sefira?

Tags: minhag, music, sefirat-ha-omer, communities

As many of our users are likely aware, there is a custom to refrain from listening to music during the Omer period. However, the operative word here is "custom." As such, I have been wondering whether any communities have permitted listening to music during the period of Sefirat haOmer?

Comment: http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: Wow. I can't think of even one! That's how strong this minhag has become - and music prohibition isn't even mentioned in the Shulchan Aruch, IIRC! Nonetheless, I have seen a decline in stringencies in keeping this minhag, during the past 20 years. Used to be no music during all days of Sefirah except Lag B'Omer & starting 3 days before Shavu'ot. People practicing 1st 33 days respected those doing last 33 days. Now, it's the opposite - each side has to "tolerate" and "accommodate" the other minhag! I liked it the way it was.

Comment: @DanF, don't forget those who are makpid to treat Yemei HaAtzmaut v'Yerushalayim as chagim (effectively like chol hamoed IMO). Many will have concerts, parties, and the like, although most of this seems derived from secular culture, from where I'm standing.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - I didn't foget. I intentionally, did not mention this for the reason that you cited. I am "oppositely makpid" on NOT listening to music on Yom Ha'atzma'ut. (Some have called me "anti-Israel", which is a false and ludicrous claim, BTW.) Yom Yerushalayim is after the 1st 33 days according to my minhag.

Comment: There are a few heteirim out there but whole communities unlikely

Comment: I don't know the source or if this is valid but I have heard some permit recorded music and only prohibit live music during the time of sefira that they hold by

Comment: @Dude, I've heard similar. In fact, in this day and age, it's impossible to avoid the former. The local seforim store plays music even during the three weeks.